# dhtmlxgrid addRow() unusual behavior on checkbox

Tags: dhtmlx

I am trying to add rows to a grid using dhtmlx in java, following is the code.

```
var combinedColumn =  "displayText";
displayOptionsGrid.addRow(selectedID, [ displayOptionsGrid.getRowsNum() == 0 ? 1 : 0, combinedColumn]);
```

What the function is supposed to do is that if the number of rows is zero it adds the first row as checked and then the rest as unchecked. The error which I am facing is, I delete the rows one by one and try to re-add the rows in the same session with some other row at first than the row I added previously, but can't. I can only add the row which I added first previously as the first row.

When I use **grid.clearAll()** it works fine. Can someone tell me the exact thing we do in **clearAll()** which we don't in **deleteSelectedRows(**) in **dhtmlxgrid**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your selectedID attribute.

Note that each row should have a unique id, so adding a row with the id existing in your grid will break the grid.